# Extending the users package of mean.io

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack, mean.io

I am trying to create an application for sports event management system using MEAN.io 
Since it uses the modular approach, there are different packages that comes in skeleton application like `system`, `users`, `access`. What i want to do is make a new package called `players` and it should extend the users package. The players schema would contain extra fields `section` and `teams`.So how do I extend the User Schema of `users` package in `players` package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your players package be dependent on users.

`Players.register(function(app, auth, users, database) {...});`

You now have access to the database and can load the user schema with

`var userModel = database.connection.model('User');`

and you can use the schema.add function to extend the schema

`userModel.schema.add({ scrore: 'string'});`

This should add the score field to the user model

I think this might work for you. But I was told from a member of mongoose team that schema.add only works before compiling the model. See this link for more info about schema add http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-add

Comment: ok i have kept this in app.js of players package and it works. But how do we do it from players/models.js. I don't want to keep extended schema in app.js

Comment: And why is not mean.io keeping the users and access package in published package?I think keeping these packages at the node_modules would be better instead of including in default skeleton app.

Comment: hi Deepak, in the next release coming up pretty soon the user, access etc will be proper packages as part of the network. We will probablly blog about that soon. re: using the model.js, it is a problem due to overriding dependencies. Open an issue for that on github and we can address it formally

Comment: I am eagerly waiting for the next release :)