# Modularization of a MEAN project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I'm currently working at a project which uses these main technologies: - node.js - express - mongodb + mongoose - bootstrap - angularjs + angular-material

A MEAN project, putting it simple.

Because the resulting application will be installed in different environments, I need to organize the project in modules in order to have the possibility to choose exactly which modules will be installed. I don't know how to do it, I've looked at Yeoman, npm+bower and docker but I don't think those are the right choice for this kind of problem. I want to edit only one file, in which I specify which modules I really need for that specific installation.

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [meain.io](http://mean.io/). It has modular structure.

PACKAGES
Everything in mean.io is a package and when extending mean with custom functionality make sure you create your own package and do not alter the core packages.

The mean.io package system allows developers to create modular code that provides useful tools that other mean developers can use. The packages, when published, are plug-and-play and are used in a way very similar to traditional npm packages.

The mean.io package system integrates all the packages into the mean project as if the code was part of mean itself and provides the developers with all the necessary tools required to integrate their package into the host project.

**There are two types of packages:**

**Custom Packages** are generated by the mean scaffolder and contain most of your application logic. Custom packages are found in /packages/custom and can be published as a contrib package for use by other developers.
Contrib Packages are installed by the mean installer and are found at /packages/contrib. Contrib packages are “plug and play”.

**Core Packages**
All Core packages can be overridden by other packages allowing you to extend and adapt it to fit your specific needs.

More details [here](http://learn.mean.io/#mean-stack-packages)

Comment: Mean.io can be one solution, thanks, but it has some problems. It force me to wrap everything inside a package and that's good. But i don't want to use any existing package since I already handle everything by myself. Another problem is that mean force me to use a fixed structure which it's not so good, for example the client code is separated by concepts (controllers, modules, ...) and not by logic and that's not an angular best practice. Can I avoid to use any mean.io default package and change the structure?

Comment: Of course you can change it. I am using angular fullstack for our large scale project I changed it's structure and make it suitable for our project. You can also change everything you need in mean.io. It is just a javascript codes. Instead  of building such project structure by yourself you can get an idea of how to build this and you can use some of it's parts which is suitable for you or you can just change some behaviours of mean.io and make it suitable for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So I'll try using mean.io, it seems that's the answer :) Last question about this packaging system. If I need to create a new package which needs to edit an existing mongodb document (defined inside another package) adding a new field how can I do? Maybe using mongodb $set?

Comment: You can edit/delete any mongodb document in any package. Eg. var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    User = mongoose.model('User'),
    _ = require('lodash');  var user = new User(req.body); user.save();

Comment: You can look at core packages of mean.io for getting better idea. For example how admin package interacts with user package etc.

Comment: Sorry, i meant schema, not model. For example I have already defined inside the package 'A' the User schema like this: new Schema({email:    String, password: String}) and i want it to become Schema({email:    String, password: String, phone: String}) inside package 'B'. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes , actually it is possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781499/extending-the-users-package-of-mean-io , http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-add

Comment: P.S. If my answer helped you, you can upvote or accept my answer, I would be glad for this ))